# How to reduce apk for my app, When creating apk lib folder contains diff app engine support how to make it split?

Tags: android, dependencies, size, apk

How to reduce apk size when releasing signed apk from my app module, 
I tried

In my Gradle file I have added these dependencies

```
    compile project(':v-plus')
    compile project(':android-pdf-viewer')
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:27.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:customtabs:27.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:11.4.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.4.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.4.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.4.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.4.2'
    compile 'com.facebook.network.connectionclass:connectionclass:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.+'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    compile 'me.relex:circleindicator:1.2.2@aar'
    compile 'com.firebase:firebase-jobdispatcher:0.8.4'
    compile 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:1.1.61'
```

By using above and after creating release apk, the size became 28 MB, how can I fix that.

Comment: Most of the apk size is due to the resources that are used. Check for large image size and compress them as required.

Comment: Yeah, in parallel any third party library dependency is also related for apk size increase, I am using split apk feature so that apk size reduced to 7 MB. Thanks for your message